# How do I match the content of two HTML tags? Multi-line strings inbetween them. - AS3

Tags: regex, actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, match

I want to match all contents inside the **<div class="post_body" id="pid_"></div>** tags... A sample of what I need to parse is below.

```
        <tr>

            <td class="trow2 post_content ">





                <div class="post_body" id="pid_">

                    This is <span style="font-style: italic;">just a test</span> message.<br />
With an image.<br />
[img]http://www.somesite.com/wp-content/something.jpg[/img]<br />
Blah blah <span style="font-weight: bold;">blah</span>.<br />
<br />
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy <span style="text-decoration: underline;">dawg</span>.<br />
<br />
[video=youtube]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MbYZa4gTxzM[/video]<br />
<br />
<a href="mailto:test@test.com">asd</a><br />
<ul>
<li>item number 1</li>
<li>item nubmer 2<br />
</li></ul>
<br />
<div class="codeblock phpcodeblock"><div class="title">PHP Code:<br />
</div><div class="body"><div dir="ltr"><code><span style="color: #66CCFF">&lt;?php&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #7AC07C">echo&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #FF99FF">'hello&nbsp;world'</span><span style="color: #7AC07C">;&nbsp;</span><span style="color: #66CCFF">?&gt;</span></code></div></div></div>
<br />
<div style="text-align: center;">i am centered.</div>
<div style="text-align: right;">i am not centered.</div>

                </div>







                <div class="post_meta" id="post_meta_">



                </div>

            </td>

        </tr>
```

As you can see, I **intentionally** added a whole bunch of stuff in-between the tags. This was the part where I needed help for. How do I detect the insides of the two tags I specified above given the fact that there are other tags in their way.

This is done in AS3 on Flash Builder.

Comment: What are you trying to match?

Comment: I'm trying to match the content of <div class="post_body" id="pid_"></div>

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML is XHTML, you can use XPath to parse and get the values inside those tags. See this question [Parsing XML/XHTML in Actionscript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283484/parsing-xml-xhtml-in-actionscript)