# Using Actionscript 2.0 to access <div> value in XHTML file

Tags: xhtml, actionscript-2, flash-cs5

I have a (.xhtml) file that I need to access a particular `<div>` from my flash movie using Actionscript 2.0.

My (.xhtml) file is roughly in this format:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Landing</title>
</head>
<div id="mainArea">
    <div id="content">
        <div id="calloutContent">
            <div id="callout1">Search Our QA Database</div>
        </div>
        <div id="TitleContent">
            <div id="title1">Heading One</div>
            <div id="title2">Heading Two</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to access the value of `<div "title1">`, so that would be the text "Heading One", then I need to assign that to a variable in my flash move, then display it in a text field. I have looked at "XPathAPI", but I just cannot get it working, as the file is not pure XML.

I have looked at loading XML, and access nodes within that, which works fine, but when I try (.xhtml), in the format above, I just cannot get it to work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. If you need any further information, please let me know.

Thanks, I am a bit desperate.

Alan...

Comment: Have you tried this solution? - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/283484/parsing-xml-xhtml-in-actionscript

Answer (score 0):

Using meta tags you can send variables into a flash file when embedding the swf file onto a page... I don't remember how exactly but 1 quick google should reveal it... after that if the value int he div will be changing just use javascript to keep up with it.. or php..

Comment: Thanks for the answer. However, to comply with a client's framework, we have to undertake as per the example xhtml file, so no meta data manipulation. The file will be embedded into the XHTML, using swfobject.js and "flashvars" to pass in variables. And the code to grab the `<div>` has to happen in Actionscript. Any other ideas...thanks.